# Stripe identity document upload error

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-connect

The following error is appearing while trying to upload identity document using stripe API.The code is used is also given below.Please help.!
Thanks in advance.

The php code that I used is

```
require '.././libs/stripe-php/init.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_abc123'); 

$fileName = "success.png";

$fp = fopen($fileName, "r");

$file_obj = \Stripe\FileUpload::create(
    array(
        "purpose" => "identity_document",
        "file" => $fp
    ),
    array(
        "stripe_account" => 'acct_1AbC123'
    )
);

$file = $file_obj->id;

$response['status'] = $file;
```

Response is given below.

```
Stripe\Error\ApiConnection: Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 26]: couldn't open file "success.png") in C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php:277
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php(234): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->handleCurlError('https://uploads...', 26, 'couldn't open f...', 0)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php(196): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->executeRequestWithRetries(Array, 'https://uploads...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(271): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->request('post', 'https://uploads...', Array, Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(60): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/files', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\ApiOperations\Request.php(56): Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/files', Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\stripe-php\lib\ApiOperations\Create.php(23): Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/files', Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\v1\index.php(318): Stripe\FileUpload::create(Array, Array)
#7 [internal function]: {closure}()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Route.php(468): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Slim.php(1355): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Middleware\Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\libs\Slim\Slim.php(1300): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\v1\index.php(745): Slim\Slim->run()
#15 {main}{"status":"3"}
```

In order to confirm that the file was there.I used the following code

$fileName = "success.png";

```
if (!file_exists($fileName))
  {
      echo "Cannot find file.";
  } else {  
      $fp = fopen($fileName, "rt")or die("Unable to open");
      echo "b".var_dump($fp);
  }
```

And the response was " bresource(108) of type (stream) " which means file is there .Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a file `"success.png"` on your server? The issue is that your code is trying to open a file that may not exist. If it does exist, does it have the correct permissions to be read by your PHP script?

Comment: Yes I have double checked It's there ..! I have used the following code alone to see if file is opening and it was opening. 
$fileHandle = fopen("success.png", "r")or die("Unable to open");

Comment: Hi has anyone checked on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself.The issue was with the TLS version 1.1 on local server.On Windows 10 OS you have option to choose the TLS version to use by following the below given steps.
1.Open Internet options from control panal
2.Select advanced tab
3.Scroll to bottom and there you can find check boxes of TLS versions.

Please note that this solution is what I found for my windows localhost.
Thanks.